# mySQL precison error

Tags: mysql, precision

I have the following mySQL structure

```
id               double PK
datenum          double(12,11)
Timestamp        varchar(25)
Min_F1_baro_20_  float
Max_F1_baro_20_  float
Mean_F1_baro_20_ float
```

but when I'm trying to insert a value I get the following error:

**UPDATED**

```
ERROR 1264: Out of range value for column 'datenum' at row 1
```

SQL Statement:

```
INSERT INTO `forwind`.`metozean_aggregateddata_fino_0_01666667_14_01_2010_00_00` (`id`, `datenum`, `Timestamp`, `Min_F1_baro_20_`, `Max_F1_baro_20_`, `Mean_F1_baro_20_`) VALUES (1, 435.34, '2011-12-12 12:12:12', 12, 12, 12)
```

Comment: What insert query are you using?

Comment: what are the values you are trying to insert?

Comment: don't use doubles for primary keys!! with double you can never be sure that (1 = 2-1) is true due to rounding errors. Use integers for PK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`double(12,11)`** is way too precise I think ;-)

**Edit**: I mean, try `double(12,4)` or whatever you need; `(12,11)` is "out of range" of double precision